# How do i verify on my click event the tab option has displayed the data in selenium?

Tags: selenium

As per attached image '7' tabs are there. 
for each tab the code is as follow. The nav tag contains 7 anchor tags.

```
 <nav id="tblDetailsLinks" class="nav modal-patient-navtabs" xpath="1">
            <a href="#" onclick="objDetail.SelectTab(this, '745'); return false;" name="DetailTabLink" id="tabCases" class="nav-link modal-patient-navtabs-tab TabWidthCss" data-name="CaseManagement" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="Cases" aria-selected="false" style="width: 12.5%; text-align: center;">
            CASES
            </a>
    </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="objDetail.SelectTab(this, '745'); return false;" name="DetailTabLink" id="tabIntake" class="nav-link modal-patient-navtabs-tab TabWidthCss" data-name="Intake" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="Intake" aria-selected="false" style="width: 12.5%; text-align: center; display: none;">
    INTAKE
    </a>
```

I have to click on each and every link and just wanted to verify whether the data has been displayed or not. I have tried with the following code:

```
public void SecondaryDetails() throws IOException, Exception {

    for(int i=0; i<tabOptionsList.size(); i++)
            {            

                tabOptionsList.get(i).click();
                Thread.sleep(3000);

                    if(tabOptionsList.get(i).isDisplayed())
                    {
                        System.out.println(tabOptionsList.get(i).getText() + " details has been displayed");
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Clicked but details has been not displayed");
                        softAssert.fail("Failing as tab option has been not displayed");}
                    softAssert.assertAll();
            }
        }
```

On every click its showing completely different data, nothing common on each click which i can mention in above code like contains text() something like.

The code is running fine clicking on each and every tab and displays the data.  My question is "my above code is right to verify whether the data has been displayed on screen for all tab options after clicking on each tab/link it. Please note its also not opening a new page after every click.[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/PovCK.png] Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you'll need to use a locator that would confirm that content has been loaded.  Maybe some kind of header type text that describes the information below it?

Comment: maybe you can assert that that box is not empty

Comment: @pcalkins, there is no common text after clicking on each tab, how can i put it in for loop if its not common for all options.

Comment: @Adrian, can you say elaborate your suggestion.

Comment: after you click there is some kind of expected behavior.  You need to test for that behavior.  I'm guessing the DOM is updated after you click, so you need to test for whatever updates are expected to happen.  I can't be very specific here because you haven't posted the markup before/after each click.  If there is nothing specific text-wise for each click, you would test the structure of the markup... maybe a count of elements or something like that.

Comment: for example you can say myElement.getText() //this will give some text we dont care what it is after you have that text do something like .... Assert.assertequals (myElement.getText(), !"") or something like if(MyElement.getText().equals("") || myElement.getText.isnotEmpty)

Comment: Thanks, let me try. I have just posted another question related to whether file has been downloaded successfully or not? please help if you have any idea.

Comment: @Adrain, i tried what you suggested but as myElement when trying to take path for it, it gives a different div tag with different id and having the details of each individual tab. When i am clicking on each of the tab its giving relevant data in a rectangle box which is div tag.

Comment: May i know why my question is eligible for 'Bounty'?